# Transparent with quaqua

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

I use the following code to view seperate frames.

```
public JDialog getDDisplay(String title, JPanel panel) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame(title + "::.");
    f.setTitle(title + "::.");
    f.setResizable(false);       
    JDialog d = new JDialog(f);
    d.add(panel);
    d.setResizable(false);
    d.setTitle(title + "::.");
    d.pack();
    d.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    d.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    if (verticle) {
        JRootPane root = d.getRootPane();
        root.setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
        root.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        root.putClientProperty("Quaqua.RootPane.isVertical", Boolean.TRUE);
        root.putClientProperty("Quaqua.RootPane.isPalette", Boolean.TRUE);            
    }
    return d; 
}
```

Any one tell my how can I set trasparency with quaqua (for JDialogs,JOptionpanes,Jpanels etc) I read their [documentation](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/guide/index.html) . But couldn't found on transparency.

Comment: Why are you creating a dummy JFrame to link the JDialog to rather than using an existing JFrame or other top-level window?

Comment: Here my code is for just for an example and not about using JFrames.The way using JFrames can be differed according to the its situation. My question is how to set transparent to JComponents(ex: JPanels etc.) with quaqua them.